# Is it possible to add HTTP headers to a Socket.io handshake?

Tags: session, authentication, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to secure the channel between my socket.io client and the node.js side. The main web application is in Drupal so I can't pass the cookies to node.js if node.js is on another host. I'd like to add some custom headers to he Socket.io HTTP handshake (like the PHP session).
Do you know if it is possible?
Using Socket.io 0.7

Answer (score 2):

**P.S: I am just brainstorming here a little bit. I like this problem and am going to think a little bit more about this. I only thought about it yet from node.js same domain only...**

### Github issue

I don't know(don't think so) if it is possible to add headers. 
**P.S: I think you should also try to fill issue at https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues. The nice thing about github is that author will receive an email when somebody posts an issue. Also the people at learnboost are really nice people who like to help you out.**

### Proxy

Proxy all your request so that request come from same domain.

### Refererer

The refererer is passed so you can pass information from this. This can also be spoofed so you better create something you can validate(only once) from Drupal. I guess this would be pretty easy to implement...

### only allow message-flowing after verification.

What I know you can do is disconnect sockets via `socket.disconnect()`. Open connection and retrieve socket.io's id, but only accept messages after identity has been approved. I would make a route available via express which Drupal can curl `post` socket.io's id to to (keep route private). Because you are inside Drupal's domain you can access Drupal's session information.

```
// v0.7.x
var sid = socket.id;
```

To make this secure the only option is to use SSL(that is the only way you can make any communication link secure anyway). If you trust both domain's SSL is probably not really necessary. Then if socket.io's id is allowed you will allow message-flowing else I would just disconnect the connection.

## PusherApp

Another option would be to implement/clone pusherapp authentication => http://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_channels#subscribe-private-channels

[image: authentication]

**P.S: I will to try and upload an example later, but for now it is time for me sleep. Hopefully this made any sense :)...**

Comment: As I said, the problem is that Drupal and the Node.js server are not on the same host. The socket.io logic in a Drupal page, so the Drupal cookies are not passed to the host where Node.js lives. (I upvoted your answer on the other thread, and stole the parse_cookie helper :))

Comment: @claudio you are right :$. I missed the other host part so that session/cookies are not shared :$. I think I know how you what want but not by adding headers. Please wait a couple of minutes for me to try it out and update my answer...

Comment: Thank you very much for the brainstorming (I'm doing it a lot too)! Another thing to consider is that if the cookie is NOT *host specific*, the issue is quite less serious as it seems: I could use the "www.myserver.com" for web, and "node.myserver.com" for the socket.io endpoint. The TCP port seems not to be an issue.

Comment: I see you added issue to github. Hopefully Guillermo can come up with a clean solution.